# Removing redundancy when declaring internal constants in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm using Kotlin 1.4 and have a  `MyConstants.kt`  file with these contents:

```
@file:JvmName("MyConstants")
package my.package
internal const val A = 1
internal const val B = 2
```

Since I want to have a few dozens constants I would like to know if there's a way to avoid specifying  `internal`  for each constant.
Without having to introduce companion objects or have any kind of instantiation.

Comment: Do your constants need to be accessible only inside your module?

Comment: @kdev yes, only inside the module

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, not with constants like that.

An `enum class` could be an alternative. There are two options in that case:

**Explicit enum values**

```kotlin
internal enum class MyConstants(val number: Int) {
    A(1),
    B(2)
}
```

*Implicit values by using the ordinal**

```kotlin
internal enum class MyConstants {
    A,
    B
}

val number = MyConstants.A.ordinal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object class for your constants like this

```
package my.package
object MyConstants {

val A = 1
val B = 2

}
```

and you can access this like

```
MyConstants.A
```